# Variable "salon" does not exist - (twig error) - get salon_id

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my layout I would like to get the view of the salon_edit by the id salon.
Here is the symfony2 error "Variable "salon" does not exist" at the lign 61 ->  `<a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id':salon.id }) }}" class="link_pink">Mon compte salon</a>`

Could you help me please ?

Here is the twig's portion with this lign

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            {% if is_granted('ROLE_SALON') %}
                                <a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id':salon.id }) }}" class="link_pink">Mon compte salon</a>
                            {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                                <a href=# class="link_pink">Mon compte</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}" class="link_rouge">Se déconnecter</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li>
                            <a class="link_pink" href="{{ path('user_inscription') }}">S'inscrire</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
```

Here is my function from saloncontroller

```
    /**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing salon entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="salon_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Salon $salon)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($salon);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('SalonBundle\Form\SalonType', $salon);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('salon_edit', array('id' => $salon->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('@Salon/salon/edit.html.twig', array(
        'salon' => $salon,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

The stack trace

```
[1] Twig_Error_Runtime: Variable "salon" does not exist.
at n/a
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/src/CoreBundle/Resources/views/Default/layout.html.twig line 61

at __TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82->{closure}()
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/twig/66/66beb7ecc8aa1a0e9315e0eddb676910b6afc28c60b27e59e4cc417df7bde814.php line 128

at __TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82->block_header(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('title' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_title'), 'stylesheets' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_stylesheets'), 'header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body'), 'javascripts' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_javascripts'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4577

at Twig_Template->displayBlock('header', array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('title' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_title'), 'stylesheets' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_stylesheets'), 'header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body'), 'javascripts' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_javascripts'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/twig/7a/7a92fc34297bb697cff5b7a080558e7f9d95ea471251008ab1f7e7390b0deb5a.php line 51

at __TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528->doDisplay(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('title' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_title'), 'stylesheets' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_stylesheets'), 'header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body'), 'javascripts' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_javascripts'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4682

at Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('title' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_title'), 'stylesheets' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_stylesheets'), 'header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body'), 'javascripts' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_5cc24ee05b63b1a2f964871f6daa7de9297002ce6686929eddf463a4e536a528), 'block_javascripts'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4663

at Twig_Template->display(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/twig/66/66beb7ecc8aa1a0e9315e0eddb676910b6afc28c60b27e59e4cc417df7bde814.php line 28

at __TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82->doDisplay(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4682

at Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('header' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_header'), 'footer' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_ff527ec479eaa508e6f0a4dde49c75ec7eaccfdd5401a5e2f3c7a5571c049b82), 'block_footer'), 'body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4663

at Twig_Template->display(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/twig/ee/ee83aa46a744063fbc1dae1a5d8c7745a1257cd4f8dc9948b21b4f2f065ab756.php line 27

at __TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6->doDisplay(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4682

at Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array('body' => array(object(__TwigTemplate_1dd3d918e01d77f295bef77124491b666956198f387af3b7a6bd384c0793c7a6), 'block_body')))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4663

at Twig_Template->display(array())
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4670

at Twig_Template->render(array())
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 50

at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render('@Core/Default/homepage.html.twig', array())
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php line 72

at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render('@Core/Default/homepage.html.twig', array())
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php line 99

at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->renderResponse('@Core/Default/homepage.html.twig', array(), object(Response))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 185

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->render('@Core/Default/homepage.html.twig')
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/src/CoreBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 11

at CoreBundle\Controller\DefaultController->indexAction()
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(DefaultController), 'indexAction'), array())
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 144

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 64

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php line 69

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 185

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /var/www/html/salon-beaute/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: did you provide a value value for `salon`? something like `return array ('salon' => $salon)` in your controller. Edit: I mean in the show controller not the edit one (because you obviously provide it in edit).

Comment: yes,in this lign `<a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id':salon.id }) }}" class="link_pink">Mon compte salon</a>` I would like to call the editAction from my SalonBundle\Controller\SalonController.
I thought I was calling this action. How to fix it ? Thank you very much

Comment: thank you @mikdev. Yes I have already this in my showAction   public function showAction(Salon $salon)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($salon);

        return $this->render('@Salon/salon/show.html.twig', array(
            'salon' => $salon,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

Comment: can you update your question and provide `showAction()`?

Comment: here is my showaction     /**
     * Finds and displays a salon entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="salon_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Salon $salon)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($salon);

        return $this->render('@Salon/salon/show.html.twig', array(
            'salon' => $salon,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

Comment: But what I want is to go directly to the edit page of the salon.

Comment: Try to change `return $this->redirectToRoute('salon_edit', array('id' => $salon->getId()));` to `return $this->redirectToRoute('salon_edit', array('id' => $salon->getId(), 'salon' => $salon ));`

Comment: tk @mickdev. No unfortunatly that's not working :-(. Maybe because there is a salon_id but first a salon is logged like a user ?

Comment: Ah ok ! You want the current user (salon) to access it's edit page, right ? Try something like this `<a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id': app.user.id  }) }}" class="link_pink">Mon compte salon</a>`

Comment: thk ! I tried this (and it appeared another bug).In fact,  In fact my salon doesn't get the id user...I made a dump in my newAction. Maybe because of that ?

Comment: In fact I dont't get the current user id from my saloncontroller....I 'm lost

Comment: If you can't access global variables, you should try to solve this issue first : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#global-variables

Comment: Yes now it's work. Now in my newActionSalon I get the current user. So now when I'm logged as role_salon with my user_id I can go directly to my edit_salon. And the correct code is ` {% if is_granted('ROLE_SALON') %} <a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id':app.user.salon.id }) }}">Mon compte salon</a>`.

Comment: Unfortunatly I have to declare the good result by comment. I cannot understand why I need reputation for answering ! Thk @mickdev and Pierrick

Comment: Nice ! I was very close with `app.user.id`. You can ask @Pierrick Martellière to post it as he need reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an array of salons called salons. If you wanna have access to have you have to go through a twig for a loop. So in your:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SALON') %}
    <a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id':salon.id }) }}" class="link_pink">Mon compte salon</a>
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href=# class="link_pink">Mon compte</a>
{% endif %}
```

you have to modify to:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SALON') %}
    {% for salon in salons %}
        <a href="{{ path('salon_edit', { 'id':salon.id }) }}" class="link_pink">Mon compte salon</a>
    {%endfor%}
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href=# class="link_pink">Mon compte</a>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT 1: Can you provide the Request Attributes section's content in the profiler

Comment: thx to @mickdev who keeps downvoting my good points instead of searching for answering the question.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question about the Request Attributes section's content in the profiler

Comment: @PierrickMartellière I did not down vote your answer. Instead of accusing, go to my profile and check first. Anyway, you received down vote from other members because you were spamming instead of answering the question. I'm here to help, gaining points is the least of my worries. Now can we back helping people ? Thanks.

Comment: @mickdev No worries, I told him I did it, moderator came along after the flags we raised. All good now :)

Comment: I'm requesting this to see what route he's asking because he seems to melt some concepts

Answer (score 0):

if you are try to access variable to parent template then try this, maybe it work

{% set salonParentVar = salon %}